# AngularJS can't pass in different function when directive coupled with controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which I want to tightly couple with a controller as a component. I assumed I was following best practice by explicitly passing ion my functions even though I was declaring the controller to use. Here is an example:

*app.js*

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

app

 .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.output = '';
   $scope.foo = function () {
     $scope.output = 'foo';
   }
   $scope.bar = function () {
     $scope.output = 'bar';
   }

 })

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      output: '=',
      foo: '&',
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    replace: true,
    controller: 'myCtrl',
  };
})
```

*template.html*

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="foo()">Click Foo</button>
  <p>You clicked: <span style="color:red">{{output}}</span></p>
</div>
```

*index.html*

```
<body>
  <my-directive
   output="output"
   foo="bar()">  <!-- pass in the *bar* function instead of the *foo* function -->
  </my-directive>
</body>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4lhxuXbK9YbjAklR7v1?p=preview

Here, even though I'm passing in the `bar()` function, the output is 'foo' when the button is clicked. If I uncouple the controller by commenting out `controller: 'myCtrl'` in the directive, the output becomes 'bar'.

I thought I could declare the controller but still be free to pass in which functions I desire to the directive. It also seems that explicitly passing these functions in is a little redundant if the directive just looks up to the controller to find it (I can pass nothing into the directive and it still works).

This is especially problematic when testing as I would like to pass in my own stub functions to the directive, which at the moment I cannot do.

Is there some way to achieve what I want or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

**EDIT** I meant to not have the controller declared in the HTML.

Comment: Your directive and html uses the same controller? so both the functions are defined. just remove `controller: 'myCtrl',` from directive

Comment: Are they?  Won't they be different instances of MyCtrl?

Comment: Yes, that was actually an error on my part. I want to eliminate `ng-controller` in the html, abd couple the controller in the directive. I still have the same problem though.

Comment: You should not declare `$scope.foo = ..` in your controller as it is already existant and passed via data-binding (otherwise you loose the reference to th passed `bar()`)

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `controller` property on the directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      output: '=',
      foo: '&',
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    replace: true,
    // controller: 'myCtrl',
  };
})
```

You're wiring up the same controller to the directive as the parent, which is overwriting all the properties you're trying to pass in via isolate scope. The controller is wired up **twice**, once on the parent scope and then again on the directive. Removing this will allow you to pass in the function `bar()` and it will not be overwritten.

Here's the [Plunker Demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/TQQucf3Ae86TGScLeKC0?p=preview)

Comment: Agh. My Bad. I actually don't want to have `ng-controller` in there at all. If I remove it, I still want to couple my controller in the directive and I get the same result. http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4lhxuXbK9YbjAklR7v1?p=preview

Comment: In your new example, the `bar()` expression will not work since `bar` is not defined on the parent scope. However, you won't see that result since the controller overwrites the `foo` property as a different function.

Comment: There might be some confusion behind the `controller` property and `scope` property on the DDO. The `scope` property will create an isolate scope where you take in values or evaluate expressions on the parent scope. The `controller` property just wires up a controller to that directive with that directive's scope, it does not create a parent-child scope relationship.

Comment: So I guess my question is: can I declare the controller just in the directive but still be free to pass in any function from the controller to the directive (i.e. switching out `foo` for `bar` in the template)?

Comment: Definitely, the `$scope` service in the controller will give you access to everything on the directive's scope. You can add/remove/change any of the directive's `$scope` properties from there.

Comment: Maybe I'm being really dense then, but how do I get the directive to accept the `bar` function instead of `foo` in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4lhxuXbK9YbjAklR7v1?p=preview

Comment: To be clear, I want to do this so that in testing I can throw in dummy functions to the directive.

Comment: OK, I can't see any way to achieve what I want without declaring `ng-controller` in the template :(

Comment: Hey, sorry been off the last 4 hours. It does seem like Joe Enzminger's solution below would offer you the functionality you're looking for. If you check to see if `foo` is already declared on the scope before writing to it, it should default to the value you're passing in through the scope binding. Here's a plnkr with that working :http://plnkr.co/edit/0mIyj7KRd4N8eCuCEAYD?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I see in that plunkr example it is necessary to declare `ng-controller` in the html. I was really looking for a method whereby I could do away with `ng-controller` altogether by attaching the controller directly to the directive, but still pass in arbitrary arguments, which would help in testing.

Comment: You can, but in these examples without the `ng-controller` there isn't anything on the parent scope to pass in

Answer (score 0):

When running inside a directive, the $scope is initialized with output and foo variables before the controller constructor is called.  Your controller is essentially overwriting these properties.

A simple check in your controller

```
if(!$scope.foo)
{
    $scope.foo = function () {
    $scope.output = 'foo';
    }
}
```

Would work.

PS.  I'm assuming your example is a simplification of your problem.  If it's not, then the other answer's advice to simply remove the controller from the directive is the best approach.